# Contraction Mapping on Closed Ball Induced by the Euclidean Norm

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be the closed unit ball in $\Bbb R$$^n$ with the metric d induced by the Euclidean norm.  Suppose the mapping satisfies

d(Tx, Ty) $\leq$ d(x, y) for all x, y in $\Omega$

Prove there exists at least one fixed point of T.

I’ve been researching how to do this problem, and my best bet is to use the Brouwer Fixed-Point Theorem.  However, what does it mean by “induced by the Euclidean norm”?

Comment: It merely means that $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. Interestingly enough, there is an alternative approach though, of course, the Brouwer FPT does the job too.

Comment: @fedja what would the alternative approach be?

Comment: Denote the unit ball in Rⁿ by Bⁿ := B(0; 1) = {x ∈ R ⁿ : |x|≤1} and the unit sphere (the boundary of the unit ball) by S ⁿ⁻¹ := {x ∈ R n : |x|=1} = ∂Bⁿ.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Browder-Kirk FPT. See page 13 in http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~prazak/uceni/101/Literatura/vittorino-FP.pdf for the proof in the Hilbert space (or google it yourself)